# Rails Populate Existing Join Table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, join

So I have two tables, a Customers table and a Companies table. I have also created an empty Employees table that I would like to use as a join table.

These are the associations I have: (I want customers to be associated with their respective company)

```
class Company < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :employees
  has_many :customers, :through => :employees
end

class Customer < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :employees
end

class Employee < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :customer
  belongs_to :company
end
```

Where would be the best way to do this? In my Customer#new method in the controller? I read that I need to use <<, but I don't know how to approach that.

Comment: Does a `customer` belong to or have many `employees`? Does an `employee` belong to or have one `customer`? Right now you have `belongs_to` going in both directions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the concept of Inverse association here: 
class Customer has_many :companies, :through => :employees

Comment: Do I need to add the customer_id column and company_id columns through a migration or will it do it automatically?

Comment: You will always need to add columns in your join table(employees in your case). Migrations are always needed to back your ActiveRecord assossiations.

Comment: Thank you so much. Currently learning Rails and am trying to do some more 'complex' db relations. You helped a lot.

Comment: Always there to help :) you can PM me for help as well

Answer (score 0):

You could just try delegating the company call on customers to their employee:

customer.rb

```
delegate :company, to: :employee
```

Now whenever you ask a customer its company, it will ask its employee to handle it.